# Thread scheduling when releasing lock

Tags: c++, multithreading, mutex

My expectation when unlocking a mutex was that the scheduler checks for other threads currently trying to lock this mutex and then execute one of those waiting threads. I wrote a test program (see code below) with 2 threads both trying to acquire the same mutex in a loop and do some work (sleep for 1ms). The difference is that one thread `t1` waits a short while between unlocking and trying to reacquire the mutex and the other thread `t2` doesn’t. I was expecting that both threads acquire the mutex about the same number of times. However, on windows `t1` often acquires the mutex only a single time and the other thread hundreds of times. On linux the behavior is different and both threads get work done with `t2` roughly twice as many. Why does `t1` on windows almost never acquire the mutex? How do I have to modify the code so that it does?

Example code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    mutex m;
    atomic<bool> go(false);
    int t1Counter = 0, t2Counter = 0;

    thread t1([&] {
        while(!go);
        while(go) {
            this_thread::sleep_for(100us);
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(m);
            this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
            ++t1Counter;
        }
    });
    thread t2([&] {
        while(!go);
        while(go) {
            lock_guard<mutex> lg(m);
            this_thread::sleep_for(1ms);
            ++t2Counter;
        }
    });

    go = true;
    this_thread::sleep_for(1s);
    go = false;
    t1.join();
    t2.join();

    cout << t1Counter << " " << t2Counter << endl;
}
```

Comment: The search terms you are looking for are "fairness" and "starvation". Windows mutex doesn't guarantee fairness. I'm not familiar with Linux; looks like its implementation is more fair.

Comment: Calling `std::this_thread::yield` between unlock and relock might change the picture somewhat.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Doesn't really change much. Thread t1 runs about ~5 times instead of only once, but t2 still runs hundred of times.

Comment: Accidental synchronization problem, those sleep_for() calls are not innocent.  You can tell something is amiss from the t2Counter value.  If t2 runs (nearly) unimpeded then the value should be close to a 1000.  My crystal ball says that you see something closer to 60 or 95.  On Windows, a sleep can only complete at the clock tick interrupt, it ticks 64 times per second by default.

Comment: @HansPassant You are right. Replacing the sleep_for with some busy waiting sleep does give much more sensible results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On Windows, `std::mutex` is implemented using a slim reader/writer lock.  This lock implementation is not fair (meaning that it provides no guarantees about the order in which waiting threads will acquire the lock).  Windows moved away from fair locks some time ago because Microsoft deemed lock convoys a more serious problem than thread starvation.

You can read more about slim reader/writer locks on Microsoft docs: [Slim Reader/Writer (SRW) Locks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/sync/slim-reader-writer--srw--locks)

Joe Duffy has also blogged about the fairness versus lock convoy issue: [Anti-convoy locks in Windows Server 2003 SP1 and Windows Vista](http://joeduffyblog.com/2006/12/14/anticonvoy-locks-in-windows-server-2003-sp1-and-windows-vista/)